# Which Valérian and Laureline stories is Valerian and the City of a Thousand Planets based on?

Tags: inspiration, valerian-and-city-thousand-planets, valerian-and-laureline

There are some [29](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Val%C3%A9rian_and_Laureline_books) short stories and albums in the *Valérian and Laureline* series. Which does the film *Valerian and the City of a Thousand Planets* take elements from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There a lot of... guest appearances :)

This [article](https://io9.gizmodo.com/a-guide-to-the-epic-scifi-movie-valerian-and-the-fanta-1789112928) identifies some of them, e.g. *Kistna* from *On the Frontiers* (#13), the *Marmaka* from *Ambassador of the Shadows* (#6) and so on.

Quote:

> "Besson has confirmed that the movie will loosely be **based on the sixth volume** of the comic, Ambassador of the Shadows, first released in 1975"